# AKS Pod fail to access Azure Key Vault

Tags: docker, api, azure-keyvault, azure-aks

I have a Dockerfile which has used to build a node project and run the "az login --service-principal" command. In this node project, it will retrieve the secret value from Azure Key Vault.

I try to run this docker image locally and it can successfully return the secret I set on Azure Key Vault. However, after I deploy the same docker image to AKS, it returns 403 forbidden error. Why would it happen?

I understand that I may not use this method to get authenticated to Azure Key Vault, but why it fails?

Comment: How are you accessing key vault  from AKS pod? Can you try with Aad-Pod-Identity

Comment: @RamaraoAdapa-MT I have directly run the az login command in Dockerfile which makes the container already authenticated to access key vault. It works fine in local docker container but fails after deploy to aks

Comment: Does your Key Vault accessed from selected networks?

Answer (score 1):

403 forbidden error means that the request was authenticated (it knows the requesting identity) but the identity does not have permission to access the requested resource. There are two causes:

- There is no access policy for the identity.
- The IP address of the requesting resource is not approved in the key
  vault's firewall settings.

As you are able to access the key vault from your local, it means the error is because of the key vault's firewall settings

Check your Azure Key Vault networking settings.  If you allowed access from selected networks, make sure to add AKS VMSS scale set virtual network in the selected networks

[image]

Now, you would be able to access key vault secrets from your AKS pod

Comment: Actually I have fixed my problem by a similar solution. However, I am still not understand that the reason of failure of my previous method. Even if the key vault is in selected network and didn't allow access from other cluster, it is possible to access the key vault by using "az login --service-principal", isn't it?

Comment: Is az cli installed in the pod?

Comment: Yes. Same docker image works fine when I start it locally. But 403 error after I deploy to AKS.

Comment: this is because of the selected networks in the azure key vault. AKS cluster virtual network should be added to the selected networks in the Azure Key vault

Comment: My local network is also not added into the selected network in the Azure Key Vault. Why does it work?

Comment: "No matter the target is in which selected network, successful az login can access it from any network." Is that correct?

Comment: Does your local IP address or on premises network is added in the key vault

Comment: "No matter the target is in which selected network, successful az login can access it from any network." Is that correct? Az login will be successful. But to  access key vault, the target should be in the selected network

Comment: My local IP is not added in key vault

Comment: I am using az login --service-principal and key vault is linked to the service principal.

Comment: does your key vault is allowed access from all the networks or selected networks?

Comment: Selected network.